HTTP v1 API に移行する対応は、Push通知されるクライアント側での対応は必要でしょうか？
以下の記事を確認し、遅ればせながら対応を検討しております。
以前の HTTP から HTTP v1 に移行する - Firebase ドキュメント
記事の中では、プッシュ通知する側の変更について記載されておりますが、通知を受け取る側の対応については記載されていないように思われました。
通知を受ける側となるAndroid, iOSのアプリ側では、特に対応する必要はありませんでしょうか？
ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

APNsのペイロードが場合によって変わってしまうことがあるが、普通に使っていれば問題なし。
